# Authentication failed using volley

Tags: java, android, json, laravel, android-volley

i am trying to get token from sever (Laravel) and saving to database(android) but when sending request to server i get this error:

```
E/Volley: [276] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/api/user/login
E/Volley: [276] BasicNetwork.performRequest: Unexpected response code 401 for http://192.168.1.4:8000/api/user/login
D/error: com.android.volley.AuthFailureError
```

android code (java) :

```
  public void loginUser(String email, String password, final OnLoginResponse onLoginResponse){
            JSONObject requestJsonObject=new JSONObject();
            try {
                requestJsonObject.put("email",email);
                requestJsonObject.put("password",password);
            JsonObjectRequest request=new JsonObjectRequest(Request.Method.POST, "http://192.168.1.4:8000/api/user/login",requestJsonObject , new Response.Listener<JSONObject>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(JSONObject response) {

                    onLoginResponse.onResponse(response.optString("token"));

                    Log.d("response",response.toString());
                }

            }, new Response.ErrorListener() {
                @Override
                public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
                    Log.d("error",error.toString());
                }
            }) {
                /**
                 * Passing some request headers*
                 */
                @Override
                public Map getHeaders() throws AuthFailureError {
                    HashMap headers = new HashMap();
                    headers.put("Content-Type", "application/json");
                    headers.put("csrf-token", "X-XSRF-TOKEN");

                    return headers;
                }
            };
            request.setRetryPolicy(new DefaultRetryPolicy(18000,DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_MAX_RETRIES, DefaultRetryPolicy.DEFAULT_BACKOFF_MULT));
            Volley.newRequestQueue(context).add(request);
        } catch (JSONException e) {
            Log.e(TAG, "loginUser: "+e.toString());
        }
    }
```

i checked client using postman , that is not problem and return token without problem.

this is screenshot of postman :

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TFcOb.png)

Comment: Can you show how you do the request in postman?

Comment: yes , i sent json with format like this { username:"example" , ...} and postman return token in format Json.

Comment: Can you post the exact request you sent in Postman, either as JSON or as screenshots to check how you are sending the request header as well

Comment: of course , added screenshot.

Comment: In your screenshot you uploaded something that has a `name` which is not in your java code, it has a different endpoint `localhost` and `/register` instead in your java you have `192.168.1.4...` and `/login`. Can you also show in your right request with postman (I said right here to empathize that the screenshot doesn't look the same as the code you are trying with Java and Volley) where do you use headers like `csrf-token`?

Comment: i am so sorry , i wrong  uploaded screenshot register . i changed to login screenshot please check again. about endpoint localhost : in android program must access to localhost using ip and with localhost:8000 return error.

Comment: Ok good! Have you tried first postman and then api call through android volley or the opposite to see if it is the order of requests? Maybe you dont support in backend multiple login authentications within a defined time?

Comment: Can you outline the postman request the part where you have specified the headers?

Comment: Can you confirm either by debugging or Logging that Strings "email" and "password" are the one you expect to be to pass the authenticstion login mechanism? Can you also check in your backend the request coming from android client and if you are expecting anything in the backend layer with Laravel?

Comment: first question :yes , first postman and then api android volley. second question : i dont khow but i wanna will getting json token and this is not multiple login,is true!?!

Comment: Check if in your backend you are receiving anything from the client and try to check if you expect in backend what you get from frontend (android). Probably the issue relies either in the headers, or the variable name and password could be passed empty wrong or malformed once they reach the function login(...) in the parameters or could be an issue in backend.

Comment: ok, in android i checked emil and passowrd with breakpoint and is not return null . and in laravel i checked , Laravel got email and password (using Log). everthing is all right but after request on android sent go to Response.ErrorListener() and show : com.android.volley.AuthFailureError

Comment: That's great. Now we narrowed down the issue to be for sure in the way backend is expecting the authentication to happen. Is the code in the backend expecting some form of authentication to happens through credentials (username/password) to be sent over the headers? Something is missing in headers or not handled correctly in backend. Try to dig more in the backend part and how it is expecting things or when is triggering an authentication error

Comment: Are you getting any error in Laravel?

Comment: Probably you are receiving in Laravel an error like TokenMismatchException? Try to log and to check if that is the case

Comment: hi i am so sorry for answered late, my problem is solved.Thank you very much

Comment: Can you post how? So other can benefit from it in future! Can you check if the way you solved is either one of the option in my answer?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably the issue relies either in:

- the headers
- the variable name and password could be passed empty wrong or malformed once they reach the function login(...)
- the parameters (maybe you are expecting more from the backend side)
- could be an issue in backend (probably TokenMismatchException which relates to the `csrf-token` header I see in your Android Java code

Comment: yes , i checked password that inserted in my application (android) ,that was malformed (i understood  this issue when requesting to server using postman with password and email that inserted to app (android) i saw this error)

Comment: Great! That's nice to know that we caught the issue! Good luck!